# Data disappear from array after refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component where i add data asynchronously,using a mock post api with mirage js  and it sends its state in an async thunkn from redux toolkit.Everythings works good,but the main idea is that the data i send to redux thunk,reducer i should map and use in another component,a skill bar. So,i tried to push data from thunk into an array and export it.It works good,everytime i add a new item,it maps in the component and renders,but when i refresh the page,the component have no data,but i need to mentain the state after refresh.My app is conected to redux persistor,but i see that this doesnt help,do you know what can be the problem and how i should fix it,please?
[image]

Above you see what i mean.I enter skill name and skill range,and it should render below as a bar,but it doesnt mentain the state after refresh..
**Component that should be rendered with the data:**

```
            <div>
            <ul className="skills">
                    {skillArray.map((skill, index) => <li
                        key={skill.name}
                        style={{ width: `${skill.level}%`}}
                    >
                        <p>{skill.name}<span>{skill.level}</span></p>
                    </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
                </div>
```

Slice,in the addNewSkill action i push data to the array and i use in the component above:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'

// export const fetchSkills = createAsyncThunk(
//     'skills/fetchSkills',
//     async (_, {rejectWithValue}) => {
//        try{
//            const response = await fetch('/api/skills',{
//                method:'GET',
//            })
// //  console.log(response)
//            if(!response.ok){
//                throw new Error ('Server Error!');
//            }

//            const data = await response.json();
// // console.log(data)
//            return data;
//        } catch(error){
//            return rejectWithValue(error.message);
//        }
//     }
//     );


//     export const addNewSkill = createAsyncThunk(
//         'educations/addNewSkill',
//         async (text,range,{rejectWithValue,dispatch}) =>{
// try{
//     const skill={
//         name:text,
//         range:range
//     };

//     const response = await fetch('/api/skills',{
//         method:'POST',
//         headers:{
//             'Content-name' : 'application/json',
//         },
//         body:JSON.stringify(skill)
//     });

//     if(!response.ok){
//         throw new Error('Can\'t add skill. Server error')
//     }

//     const data = await response.json();
//     dispatch(addSkill(data))

// }catch(error){
//     return rejectWithValue(error.message);
// }
//         }
//     )


    // const setError = (state, action) => {
    //     state.status = 'rejected';
    //     state.error = action.payload;
    // }
    

// export const skillSlice = createSlice({
//     name: 'skills',
//     initialState: {
//        name:null,
//        range:null,
//         status: null,
//         error: null,
//     },
//     reducers: {
//         addSkill: (state, action) => {
//             state.name = action.payload?.name;
//             state.range = action.payload?.range;
//         },
//     // },
//     // extraReducers: {
//     //     [fetchSkills.pending]: (state, action) => {
//     //         state.status = 'loading';
//     //         state.error = null;
//     //     },
//     //     [fetchSkills.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
//     //         state.status = 'resolved';
//     //         state.skillList = action.payload;
//     //     },
//     //     [fetchSkills.rejected]: setError,
//     // },
// }}
// )
// export const { addSkill } = skillSlice.actions;
// // export const { addSkill } = skillSlice.actions
// export const selectSkill = (state) => state?.skills;
// export default skillSlice.reducer;
export const fetchSkills = createAsyncThunk(
    'skills/fetchSkills',
    async (_, {rejectWithValue}) => {
       try{
           const response = await fetch('/api/skills',{
               method:'GET',
           })
//  console.log(response)
           if(!response.ok){
               throw new Error ('Server Error!');
           }

           const data = await response.json();
// console.log(data)
           return data;
       } catch(error){
           return rejectWithValue(error.message);
       }
    }
    );

    const setError = (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'rejected';
        state.error = action.payload;
    }

    export const skillArray=[]

export const addNewSkill = createAsyncThunk(
    'skills/addNewSkill',
    async (skillData,{rejectWithValue,dispatch}) =>{
        const {skillName,skillRange} = skillData
try{
const skill = {
    name: skillName,
    range: skillRange,
};
const response = await fetch('/api/skills',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-name' : 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(skill)
});
skillArray.push(skill)
if(!response.ok){
    throw new Error('Can\'t add skill. Server error')
}

const data = await response.json();

dispatch(setSkill(data))

}catch(error){
return rejectWithValue(error.message);
}
    }
)


export const skillSlice = createSlice({
  name: "skills",
  initialState: {
    skills:[],
    status: null,
    error: null
  },
  reducers: {
    setSkill: (state, action) => {
    //   console.log("action", action.payload);
    //   state.name = action.payload?.name;
    //   state.range = action.payload?.range;
    state.skills.push(action.payload);
//  localStorage.setItem(state.name,action.payload.range)
    },
  },
  extraReducers:{
      [fetchSkills.pending]:(state,action)=>{
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.error = null;
      },
      [fetchSkills.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
        state.status = 'resolved';
        state.name = action.payload;
      },
      [fetchSkills.rejected]: setError,
  }
});


 const { setSkill } = skillSlice.actions;

export const selectSkill = (state) => state?.skill;

export default skillSlice.reducer;
```

**Root:**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import { toggleButtonReducer } from './reducers/toggleButtonReducer'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import educationReducer from '../features/education/educationSlice';
import skillReducer from '../features/skills/skillSlice'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    visibilityState: toggleButtonReducer,
    educationState: educationReducer,
    skills : skillReducer
})

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved the problem,idk if it's a good aproach,but i accesed the store directly without pushing anything.

```
 const skillList = useSelector((state)=>state.skills.skills)
    console.log("skills",skillList)
```

And maped this way :

```
<ul className="skills">
                            {skillList.map((skill, index) => <li
                                key={skill.skills.name}
                                style={{ width: `${skill.skills.level}%`}}
                            >
                                <p>{skill.skills.name}<span>{skill.skills.level}</span></p>
                            </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
```

I got the expected result,thats good,but if its a good aproach or not,i dont know.